# lotus-notes desktop settings - Applications

Tags: lotus-notes

I am trying to add applications to the end users bookmarks via desktop policies. In trying out the process I can setup an application which appears under the "Internet Explorer Links".(Dragged an open application tab on the grey 'outline' area). How can I specify a folder in which the link should appear (e.g Applications or More Bookmarks) or even a folder of my own choosing (e.g My Company Apps).